# Where to locate PIE.htc in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebug, css3pie

I needed to get CSS3 properties working on IE 7 and IE 8. So I included PIE.HTC

http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/

Now when I viewed the page in IE. I didn't see the CSS3 properties got applied. I wanted to check if the pie.htc is loaded , but couldnt find, and then I went to my friend firebug to check what are all the resources loaded in Net Tab. But I couldn't find it either. Where should it be in firebug Net tab. Any clues.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Firebug in Firefox, the reason you're not seeing PIE.htc is because htc files are only loaded by IE. Other browsers ignore them completely.

(I know that Firebug can be run in IE, in the form of Firebug Lite.  But I don't think this is what you're doing, as I don't think FB Lite has a 'Net' tab. But correct me if I'm wrong)